# Adding spring-cloud-starter-config dependency results in At least one SecurityBuilder<? extends SecurityFilterChain> needs to be specified error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-config

I've  simply added the following dependency to my Spring Boot 1.4 app :

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

In order to use Spring Cloud Config Server as an externalized configuration server.

When I boot my app I now get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: At least one SecurityBuilder<? extends SecurityFilterChain> needs to be specified. Typically this done by adding a @Configuration that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. More advanced users can invoke WebSecurity.addSecurityFilterChainBuilder directly
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:276)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:75)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fc86a60e.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$5(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fc86a60e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a1dd410.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
```

I've already got an existing Security configuration, but that extends something different:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration
```

Has anyone any ideas about this? I'm thinking perhaps my dependency has resulted in upgrading perhaps part of Spring Security which now needs to be configured differently perhaps ?

Comment: Did you try upgrading your spring cloud config version to 1.4? Can you post your complete pom.xml file?

Comment: I couldn't do that, as 1.4 isn't compatible with Spring Boot 1,4. I however have found the answer, which I'll detail below.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by the following bean not being created because adding the spring cloud dependency set management.security.default to false, thereby disabling the creation of this bean.

```
@Configuration
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean({ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.ManagementWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class})
    @ConditionalOnProperty(
        prefix = "management.security",
        name = {"enabled"},
        matchIfMissing = true
    )
    @Order(2147483637)
    protected static class ManagementWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

Comment: What is a ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration, you´ve never mentioned it before?

Comment: Pass - I just debugged the Spring Code at startup. Spring Boot 1.4 is pretty ancient now, so I'd advise upgrading first if you have any issues similar to mine.